Uniqueness of Functions in Integral Equations with Probability Densities
Let's assume that for two real-valued functions $f$ and $\tilde{f}$, it holds that $\int_{\mathbf{R}} f^K p(x) dx = \int_{\mathbf{R}} \tilde{f}^K p(x) dx$ for every integer $K$, where $p$ is a continuous probability density. Under what conditions can it be said that $f=\tilde{f}$ almost everywhere?
